# SQL order by left join including non-matches

Tags: sql, join

I have the following two tables.

```
Table: Tactic
id name
1  Tactic 1
2  Tactic 2
3  Tactic 3

Table: Activity
id Tactic_id  Date
1  2          2018-01-01
2  3          2018-01-02
```

I'm trying to have the id's in table 'Tactic' ordered by their related activity from the table 'Activity'.

I have tried to following:

```
SELECT * FROM Tactic
LEFT JOIN Activity ON Tactic.id = Activity.Tactic_id
ORDER BY Activity.Date DESC
```

But since Tactic 1 doesn't have an activity it isn't ordered the correct way, as I want Tactics without an activity to be considered to be the oldest.

I hope you are able to help me.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What if something like `CASE WHEN Activitiy.Date IS NULL THEN <ADD MAX DATE + 1> ELSE Activity.Date END`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SQL allows you to specify `NULLS LAST` or `NULLS FIRST`:

```
SELECT t.*, a.*
FROM Tactic t LEFT JOIN
     Activity a
     ON t.id = a.Tactic_id
ORDER BY a.Date DESC NULLS LAST;
```

If you database does not support this, you can use two keys in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT t.*, a.*
FROM Tactic t LEFT JOIN
     Activity a
     ON t.id = a.Tactic_id
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN a.DATE IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) DESC,  -- NULLs last
         a.Date DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing `NULL` dates from the `Activity` table with some very early date literal, e.g. `1900-01-01`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tactic t
LEFT JOIN Activity a
    ON t.id = a.Tactic_id
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(a.Date, '1900-01-01') DESC;
```

The format of the date literal may be database dependent.  For example, on Oracle we would have to use something like `DATE '1900-01-01'`, while on MySQL, Postgres, or SQL Server, the above code should work as is.

Comment: On Postgres or Oracle we would not have to use something like `DATE '1900-01-01'`  - we would use `NULLS LAST` instead.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name NULLs last?  Something against NULLs? :P